# copy rows after each other excel

Tags: excel

I have a Microsoft excell file: I want to copy 2 rows and add these to the previous row (the first row). I give an example:

```
row1 -> 0027448 R   3   1   203,45  22375   EDS001  name1 name1 eds1
row2 -> 0027448 R   3   1   203,45  22375   EDS001  name2 name2 eds1
row3 -> 0027448 R   3   1   203,45  22375   EDS001  name3 name3 eds1
```

My question is: how can I copy row1, row2 and row3 after each other: 
course without manually copying. but through formulas!

row1 ... row2 ... row3 ....

Answer (score 0):

This program made ​​me more or less a good solution. Better solutions are still welcome!
I got the Excel plugin from this website: [ASAP Utilities](http://www.asap-utilities.com/download-asap-utilities.php)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I copy `row1`, `row2` and `row3` after each other? Of course without manually copying.

If you need copying after each other vertically, row by row, that seems to be simple.

1. In the very left cell of town you can just paste link to the very first cell of `row1` (like:   `=A1`).
2. Stretch it horizontally,  then stretch the whole `row1` (with formulas) vertically to the bottom.

This will copy itself, so rows 4,5,6 will copy rows 1,2,3.
Rows 7,8,9 will copy rows 4,5,6  (and again,  it will be equal to rows 1,2,3)  and so on as long as you need.